# listView setItemChecked not working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a multi-choice dialog that pops up when a button is clicked.
The image below shows what it looks like.

[image]

Here is the problem. When I click on `select all`, I programmatically check all the items using `listView.setItemChecked(position, true)`. And that part works. But after then, when user **unchecks** a specific items in the list, I want to **uncheck** `select all`.

Below is mycode, I don't know why it's not working.

```
private CharSequence[] itemList = {"select all", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"}; 
private boolean[] itemBooleanList = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false, false};

final AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myDialog.setTitle("Select type(s)");
myDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(itemList, itemBooleanList, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
        final ListView listView = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
        if(indexSelected == 0){ // if "select all" is clicked - check/uncheck all items
            for(int i=0; i<itemList.length; i++){
                listView.setItemChecked(i, isChecked);
                itemBooleanList[i] = isChecked;
            }
        }else{
            itemBooleanList[indexSelected] = isChecked;
        }
        // now I check if all item in boolean[] are true or false, if one of the item is false, it returns false and `select all` can be unchecked                            
        final boolean areAllTrue = areBooleanAllTrue(itemBooleanList);
        listView.setItemChecked(0, areAllTrue);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemBooleanList));
    }
}).show();
```

PS: when I print `itemBooleanList`, if user unchecks an item, I do see that the boolean value at that index got set to false which means, logic is correct, it's just the `setItemChecked` that is not doing it's job.

Pls let me know if you want me to upload more code or screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following code will do the trick,

```
        final ListView listView = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
    if(indexSelected == 0){ // if "select all" is clicked - check/uncheck all items
        for(int i=0; i<itemList.length; i++){
            listView.setItemChecked(i, isChecked);
            itemBooleanList[i] = isChecked;
        }
    }else{
        itemBooleanList[indexSelected] = isChecked;
        if(!isChecked) {
            itemBooleanList[0] = false;
            listView.setItemChecked(0, false);
        }else{
            //check whether all the items are checked otherthan 'select all'
            //if true then
            //itemBooleanList[0] = true;
            //listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! Can you please explain why this worked and my earlier code didn't work?

Comment: you were not considering what will happen to 'all select' when other items are being clicked.